# Printing from the New York Times iPad App

Tags: ipad, printing

I have recently installed [Printopia](https://www.decisivetactics.com/products/printopia/) app on my MacBook so that I can print from my iPad to the various printers in my business. I have noticed that I can print from something like the Notes app just fine so I think Printopia is working as expected. However, some apps, especially like the NYTimes app, do not seem to have the print button anywhere in the interface, even within Share and More.

Any thoughts on how can I print the article that I am reading in the New York Times app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The New York Times [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/the-new-york-times/id284862083) doesn't include print functionality.

If you wish to print the article, what you can do instead is to print it via Safari.

1. Tap on the Share button within the app and either tap on **Copy** or the **Message** icon to reveal the article URL.

[image] [image]

2. Once you have the article URL, copy and paste it to open in Safari on your iPad.
3. Tap on the Share icon in Safari and you can use Safari's print command to print the article.

[image]